# what do I write in the Data_extraction_rules.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, extract, backup

So It's my first time developing an App in Android Studio and I am stuck. Every tutorial I've watched either completely ignores this or tells me something that doesn't work. Whatever anybody told me to write in there it always tells me the same problem: "Unexpected domain `activity*main.xml` `MainActivity.kt´ `´MyAdapter.kt´, expected one of root, file, database, sharedpref, external" and I don't know what that means. I'm sorry if it's an obvious answer and I'm just overlooking something.

Thank you in advance for your help!*

I already tried watching tutorials, following Android Developers, and asking ChatGPT

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.